# Color text content contained within brackets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Got an excel spreadsheet being used for some text content (I know, I know), but I'm wondering if anyone would know how to highlight specific text inside of a cell contained within brackets.

Cell would contain "Text goes here [bracketed red text] and so on and so on" with the "[bracketed red text]" a red color. Any help would be appreicated!

Comment: I think the only way you'll achieve this is with macros.  I'll see what I can work out if I get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a macro.  In *Excel 2010*, press **View**, **Macros**, **View Macros**.  Type the name "Dummy" and press **Create**.  In the new window that appears, look at the **Project** pane on the left.  Double-click the sheet you want to apply the formatting to.  Copy and paste the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Text As String
    Dim Index1 As Long
    Dim Index2 As Long
    Text = Target.Text
    Index2 = 1
    Do
        Index1 = InStr(Index2, Text, "[")
        If Index1 = 0 Then Exit Do
        Index2 = InStr(Index1, Text, "]")
        If Index2 = 0 Then Exit Do
        Target.Characters(Index1, Index2 - Index1 + 1).Font.Color = &HFF
    Loop
End Sub
```

If you want the formatting to only apply to certain cells, you can insert one of the following lines before the `Dim Text As String` line.

```
    If Target.Row <> 12 Then Exit Sub    ' Only format row "$12"
    If Target.Column <> 12 Then Exit Sub ' Only format column "$L"
```

Now, whenever you finish editing a cell on the worksheet, it will change the square brackets and the text inside to red.  It also [works] if there are [multiple] sets of [square] brackets, but [nested [brackets] will] fail.

Comment: Thanks, I had it made for my wedding.  My wife's an M too.  :-)

Comment: +2 if I could, nice going with it!  I found a site that was championing a "one cell, one color" bit, and I should have known better!